# How to add LatLng into arraylist at onLocationChanged after all changes in android?

Tags: android, arraylist

How to add LatLng into arraylist at onLocationChanged after all changes in android?

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    list.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
}

//and after run it throw nullPointerExeption....
```

Answer (score 0):

It can only be 2 cases, it is either `location` or `list` is `null`.